# Is there a way to get an average of the values in four columns with just one SQL using SQLITE?

Tags: sql, sqlite, xamarin

I have a table based on this class with column names matching all the fields in the class:

```
public class ClickHistory
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public string Yymmdd { get; set; }
    public int DayOfYear { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int BtnACount { get; set; }
    public int BtnBCount { get; set; }
    public int BtnCCount { get; set; }
    public int BtnDCount { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is to get an average value of the sam of all the Btn.. columns over all rows of the table.

Already I get a count of one row like this:

```
return db2.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT (BTNACOUNT + BTNBCOUNT + BTNCCOUNT + BTNDCOUNT) FROM CLICKHISTORY WHERE YYMMDD = " + yymmdd);
        }
```

But how can I change this so I can get an average over all rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the AVG function. You can play around with it in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b84de3/1)

But just modify your query into something like:

```
SELECT AVG(btnACount + btnBCount + btnCCount + btnDCount) FROM ClickHistory;
```

What this will do is sum all the columns, then take an average for each of these sums.